# Проверка на пустой массив строк с переходом на другой массив

Tags: c#

У меня есть текстовый файл в ресурсах в котором записан текст (любой)
`var resText = Resources.MyFileText;`
И есть массив `var test = new string[] { "1", "2"};`
Есть метод который проверяет на пустой массив:

```
 public static bool IsEmptyStringArray(string[] array)
 {
    for (int i = 0; i < array.Length; i++)
    {
       if (array[i] != null)
       {
          return false;
       }
    }
    return true;
 }
```

Я хочу в случае если в текстовом файле из ресурсов нету никакого текста, то вызывался массив `test`
Я попробовал сделать так:

```
string[] resText = new[] { Resources.MyFileText };
foreach (string service in !IsEmptyStringArray(resText) ? resText : test)
{
   Console.WriteLine(service);
}
```

По идеи если файл пустой то должно было перейти на массив test, но мне просто возвращает пустой переход на новую строку из `resText`.

Как мне реализовать переход на другой массив если предыдущий был пустой?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if (!string.isNullOrEmpty(array[i]))
```